# Dividing a file to several chunks

Tags: go, unix, split, parallel-processing

Let's assume that we have a file of 100k lines or ~2gB and we want to split it in 10 chunks of 10k lines each, so that the chunks can then be processed in parallel. Is there any way to create pointers in the starting line of each of the 10 chunks, without needing to traverse the whole file ? I was thinking of somehow dividing the file with regards to its size, so that the pointers are created every 200mB. Is this even feasible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. But you need to make some assumptions and accept that your chunks will not be exact.

Either assume a standard line length or scan a few lines and measure it. Then you multiply that by the number of lines you are aiming for and just hope it's a good estimate.

Or if you just want 10 chunks take the file size and divide by 10.

So then you jump to that point in the file, either by using lseek and read, pread, or mmap. Then you scan forward until you find the end of a line and the start of the next.

It won't be exact line counts unless you actually count every line. But it will be pretty close.

I was bored and curious so check this out:
https://github.com/zlynx/linesection